# Where to get older versions of biber?

Tags: biber, obsolete

I need a copy of biber v0.99 to go with `biblatex` v1.7 so I can test some build software in scons. I think I am right that biber v 2.2 won't work with `biblatex` v1.7.

Comment: There is a version matrix in the biber and biblatex PDF documentation. Post 2.0 biblatex, the versions are closely matched and can't be mixed and matched.

Answer (score 2):

See [biblatex-biber files at SourceForge.net](http://sourceforge.net/projects/biblatex-biber/files/biblatex-biber/), where at time of writing the oldest version is 0.9.8.